# Unable to format 64gb RAW SD card Cyclic Redundancy Check error

Tags: sd-card, chkdsk, diskpart, crc

I recently purchased a new, Silicon Power high-quality micro-SD card. I used it multiple times as a boot disk for my Raspberry Pi, each time I burned a 4gb disk image and installed the OS, then connected it to my computer and reformatted the SD card to a 64gb FAT32 filesystem with Windows' diskpart program. However, yesterday, after successfully burning the disk image, which was able to successfully boot the computer, I am unable to resize and reformat the disk. I tried using Diskpart, but i get data error (Cyclic Redundancy Check), and since a number of sites recommended chkdsk, I am unable to use chkdsk because I have a raw filesystem.

This seems like a dead end, because people recommend chkdsk to fix a cyclic redundancy check, but I cannot use chkdsk because I am stuck with a RAW filesystem, which I am unable to format because of Cyclic Redundancy Check errors. There is absolutely no important data on my drive, and I do not have any problem reformatting and clearing all the data on the drive, so I am not looking for a data recovery solution, I am looking for a solution that will allow me to use my 64gb drive again.

I am stuck, please help me recover my drive. Thank you very much!

EDIT:
I broke my Raspberry Pi, so I can no longer do any solutions that require the Raspberry Pi. However, I still have a Windows laptop running Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot it again on `Raspberry Pi` and use

```
sudo raspi-config
```

there is an option `Expand filesystem`. On the next reboot it will try to expand filesystem to the maximum size of flash. Not sure if it might help though, it sounds like flash is dieing

Comment: This will not help me, as I no longer have the Raspberry Pi :P